# How to calculate time in pine script

Tags: pine-script

With the security function I have access to all kinds of timeframes like minute, hour, day and so on. I feel I cannot use this for any calculations:

I created a condition which considers a certain number of candles. So if I want to reflect one hour in my condition I have to choose 4 candles, but if I change from the 15 minutes chart to the hourly chart, my condition considers 4 hours instead of 1.
What I need is a function that can calculate with the time from my input and the chosen time in the chart. Entering 1h in my input, means to calculate 4 bars in a 15 minutes chart.

I hope my problem is properly explained.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert both your chart's timeframe and your target (1 hour in your example) to minutes. Then simply do `your target in min / your time frame in min` to get the number of candles you need.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
targetInMin = 60

f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)
      
n_bars = targetInMin / f_resInMinutes()
plot(n_bars)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but let me be more precisely. I would like to have an input field for a so called cool down period. Within this period no further buys are allowed. This looks like:
1S or 10M or 1D or 5D 

These values have to be transformed to the number of bars for the cooldown period.
If this looks to complicated, entering the cool down period in minutes would also be fine.

I found https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#time-dates-and-sessions and I am pretty sure, the answer is on that page, but I do not get the puzzle solved.

Comment: Please ask a new question for that as it is pretty different than your original question and I believe your original question has an answer now.

Comment: Useful snippet.